# How to present a dynamically created view controller

Tags: ios, view, uiviewcontroller

I got a problem and i couldnt understand what to do.

in my app - when user logins, there are 4 options

1 - show him a dashboard screen;

2 - show him a default screen if its coming in response  (there is a parameter for this containing screen name);

3 - show change plan scree if its parameter is on in response;

4 - show change pin screen after user sets his plan.

now the problem is, how to go to default screen after setting his pin, as i dont knw screen name (view controller name, as it is dynamic, coming from server).

**Code**

```
 NSLog(@"Default Screen %@", mClient.defaultScreen);
if([mClient defaultScreen] != (id)[NSNull null] || [mClient defaultScreen].length != 0 ) {
    NSLog(@"Going to push default screen : %@", mClient.defaultScreen);
    [self pushDefaultScreen:mClient.defaultScreen];

} else {

    NSLog(@"Default screen is nil, going to load dashboard");
    [mClient setUPProgressHUDForView:self.view withLable:@"Generating Dashboard" andMessage:@"Please Wait.."];
    for(UIView *subview in [self.scrollView subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
    NSLog(@"-->    :::  Going to change here");
    [self generateDashboard];
}


if(![mClient.showSetPinScreen isEqual:[NSNull null]] && ![mClient.showSetPinScreen isEqualToString:EMPTY_STRING]) {
    NSLog(@"Parameter showSetPinScreen : %@", mClient.showSetPinScreen);
    if([mClient.showSetPinScreen    isEqualToString:STRING_VALUE_YES]) {
        NSLog(@"mClient.showSetPinScreen parameter value is Y");
        SetPinViewController *changePinViewController = [[SetPinViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SetPinViewController" bundle:nil];
        changePinViewController.isFromLogin = STRING_VALUE_YES;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:changePinViewController animated:YES];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"mClient.showSetPinScreen parameter value is N");
    }

}


if(![mClient.showCardPlanScreen isEqual:[NSNull null]] && ![mClient.showCardPlanScreen isEqualToString:EMPTY_STRING]) {
    NSLog(@"Parameter showCardPlanScreen : %@", mClient.showCardPlanScreen);
    if([mClient.showCardPlanScreen isEqualToString:STRING_VALUE_ZERO]) {
        NSLog(@"Do nothing");
    } else if([mClient.showCardPlanScreen isEqualToString:STRING_VALUE_ONE] || [mClient.showCardPlanScreen isEqualToString:STRING_VALUE_TWO]) {
        NSLog(@"Show card plan screen %@", mClient.showCardPlanScreen);
        ChangePlanViewController *changePlanVoewController = [[ChangePlanViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChangePlanViewController" bundle:nil];
        changePlanVoewController.isFromLogin = STRING_VALUE_YES;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:changePlanVoewController animated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create the 4 of them on a storyBoard, a loadingView with 4 views related to it with segues, and in your dispatch method call performSegue with the right identifier.